# Changing background colors with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a complete beginner in this field, and I am stuck with my school project which has to be done in a few days.

I've coded a page which has a white background taking the full width of the screen, what I want, is to have the left side and the right side of my page with a grey background, with the background of my content remaining white and pushed a little bit to the centre. Also, the bottom and the top has to remain the same, and as I said, I only need the right and left side to be changed.

To be more specific, the sides with grey background needs to be something like 95pixels width (which is about 2-3 centimetres).  So how do I do that with CSS? [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WhxM.png) ¦¦ [this is the end of my html although I couldn't screenshot the closing divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKcX5.png)
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Use code snippets instead of images!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a `<div>`.

First, your html structure should look like this:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Your head stuff -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <!-- Your content here, you can use every html tag in here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then your CSS should look like this:

```
body {
    /* This sets the background color of the entire page to gray */
    background:#AAA;
}

.content { /* Select the div with the "content"-class (indicated by the dot) */
    background:#FFF; /* white background */
    width:60%; /* how much space the content should take up */

    /* These two lines center the div */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

You can either write the css into a .css-file and write the following code into your `<head>` to import it (recommended):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ref="path/to/the/file.css" />
```

Or you can create a `<style></style>`-tag pair in your `<head>` and write the css in there.

Comment: Hi Stunt... firstly thank you! just one more thing to make sure as I don't know that much about. To add <div class="content"> means i have to remove <div class="container-fluid"> yeah? I am asking this because I did it on LayoutIt and then copied the code.

Comment: You can have more than one class on a div, just divide them by spaces (i.e. `<div class="content container-fluid">`). But I don't know what attributes the `container-fluid` class has so it might interfere with the `content` class. You can try having both classes on it and if it looks weird you can try to remove the `container-fluid` class.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to make 2 backgrounds, left and right, why don't you change the `background-color` of the page to grey and apply 1 background image (white) and repeat it vertically. Declare the `background-color` first in your css and then the image after. You can adjust the size of the background with `background-size`.

Useful tools: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Answer (score 0):

set the body background to gray then set white background to `container-fluid`
and set this for container-fluid :

```
.container-fluid {
margin : 0 auto;
witdh : your custom width;
}
```